# iPhone UIImagePickerController video mode

Tags: iphone

When using the UIImagePickerController, is there a way to specify the resolution of the captured video, or to restrict the length of the video (based on size).  I would love to be able to have the video capture at a standard lower res mode rather than 720P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS 3.1 or later, you can use the `videoQuality` property of `UIImagePickerController`. The values are an in the enumeration
`UIImagePickerControllerQualityType` which defines `UIImagePickerControllerQualityType{Low|Medium|High}`. The default is UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium. 4.0 and later have additional resolution options.

As for duration, the property `videoMaximumDuration` allows you to specify the maximum time in seconds.